# D3js pie chart not showing up on localhost

Tags: javascript, d3.js, localhost

still brand new to D3.js. I'm trying to test out a very simple D3.js donut graph on my local server with a Mac. I opened by localhost by using

```
       python -m http.server
```

then a message appears:

```
       Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

I then opened the page on chrome by pointing to http://localhost:8000/final%20project/

Note: the folder that contains index.html and data, js and css folders is named as "final project"

On inspector, I received the following error for d3.min.js:

> d3.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
>       at Re (d3.min.js:2)

My index.html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons8-bookmark-40.png">    

</head>

<body>
     <div class="col-md-9" id="pie-chart-area"></div>  

    <!-- JS libraries -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/d3-tip.js"></script>

<!-- Custom JS -->
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main.js:

```
function getGenderColor(genderColor) {
    var fill;
    switch(genderColor) {
      case "Teen Boys":
         fill = "#0079BB";
         break;
      case "Teen Girls":
         fill = "#9E519F";
         break;
      default:
         fill = "blue";
    }
    return fill;
}


function pieChart(chartArea) {
     var margin = {left:40, right:40, top:40, bottom:40};
     var width = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
         height = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
     var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
     var donutWidth = 75;


     // color range
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .range(["#0079BB", "#9E519F"]);

    // entire canvas
    var canvas = d3.select(chartArea)
                 .append("svg")
                 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                 .append("g")
                 .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    //define arc
    var arc = d3.arc()
         .innerRadius(radius - donutWidth)
         .outerRadius(radius);

    // import pie chart and data
     var pie = d3.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.count; })
    .sort(null);


    d3.json("data/s_gender.json", function(error,data) {
        /*if (error) return console.error(error);
          console.log('mockdata',data);*/

          data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.count = +d.count; 
    });

     var path = svg.selectAll('path')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
              return color(d.data.gender);
     });

     }); //d3.json

}

pieChart("#pie-chart-area");
```

Json file (s_gender.json):

```
[
{
 "gender":"F",
 "count":533
},
{
  "gender":"M",
  "count":260
}
]
```

There are no errors, but the chart does not show up. Could anyone help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but you should call main.js in your html file after the div where you are going to draw it. Main.js is trying to draw the graph in the `div` with `id` of `#pie-chart-area`. When it loads the div is below it and is not yet loaded so it is not able to put the chart anywhere. So place the `<script src="main.js"></script>` at the bottom just before the closing `</body>` tag and especially after the div where you want to draw the chart. Check if that helps.

Comment: Also what version of d3.js are you using? And could you comment out the console.logs and try?

Comment: @Coola Hi I have edited the post by using your suggestions. After moving main.js to the bottom and pointing d3.mini.js to https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js. I see that svg has been drawn to the canvas, but the page is still empty.

Comment: What do you see in the console / page inspection? Any errors?

Comment: @Coola no errors.

Comment: Could you create a block with your code and some sample data in blockbuilder.org? Just to make sure the d3 part works ok I can review it.

Comment: @Coola just did: https://bl.ocks.org/lydiawawa/8d28916a9fa946e6c4022f6bc418c317/2d6a8223cfceba00e13d5890733e49331cbc673b

Comment: @Coola editable version: https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/9fb92d9982f0b41b63be142ce279acf5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191827/discussion-between-coola-and-lydias).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code was mainly:

1. The code was built using D3.js v4. If you use D3.js v5 you will have to use the Promise method to parse files. Otherwise you can simply src the D3.js v4 library.
2. There were some other bugs in it such as code placement vs script source. Libraries are best loaded in the header while the Javascript which manipulates the DOM should be placed after the div which it would append to.
3. Your `getGenderColor` function was not getting called properly in your code to perform the fill.

Here is a working block showing the pie chart. https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/183847663739b944038ad973e0b7d5b4/

Please feel free to ask for any clarification in the comments below.

Comment: I hope it worked on your localhost. Only you can confirm that. Happy to help.

Comment: have you ever encountered a problem when d3.js runs on the block, but do not run on localhost? I added tool tip to the graph, but the effect only appears on the block. When run on localhost, the effect is still working in the background but does not show up in the browser.

Comment: You will have to create a new question for that to examine the code. If you are using some library to create the tooltip like `d3-tip.js` it could be that the library is not being imported in your application properly on the localhost. It is best not to use a library and create your own tooltips by appending a tooltip div and updating it on mouseover. Check this tutorial out https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/257c360b3650b9f0a52dd8257d7a2d73

Comment: would you be able to review the other post that I posted recently? I'm trying to combine multiple pie charts with the same effect, and the category of the pie chart is controlled by buttons. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55719253/d3js-switching-between-multiple-charts