# d3js Switching between multiple charts

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization

While learning on my own and being brand new to D3.js, I'm trying to create multiple pie charts with different categories switched by custom buttons.

I created an individual pie chart with effect:
https://bl.ocks.org/lydiawawa/7c385eaaf24cb4e6047c9b56866fac6e/252dfbf9f27123e5577f6c54ca7dffe6fd75714e

I hope to achieve the following effect with tooltip and label, but instead of orange and apple I would like to switch in between gender, age, and race:

Desired effect:
http://bl.ocks.org/j0hnsmith/5591116

This is what I have so far:
https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/38243015ab2ac96b6086d3bae56572b9

The most difficult part is converting the two category pie chart to three categories with tooltip and label added. I would like to have some help in achieving the effect. Thank you for any input!

**Edit**

I found the following effect with three categories recently, but I do not know how to add the label or legend to the graph that can be later used for tooltip as well:

http://bl.ocks.org/jfreels/6919598

I have tried to reshape json in the following format. Maybe in this way we can use d3.json instead of init()?

```
[
 {
   "genderC": "female",
   "gender": 533,
   "raceC": "A",
   "race": 20,
   "ageC": "0 < 12 years",
   "age": 8
 },
 {
   "genderC": "male",
   "gender": 260,
   "raceC": "A E",
   "race": 19,
   "ageC": "13 years",
   "age": 1
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "A D",
   "race": 2,
   "ageC": "14 years",
   "age": 102
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "A DE",
   "race": 1,
   "ageC": "15 years",
   "age": 195
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "A C",
   "race": 5,
   "ageC": "16 years",
   "age": 200
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "A C E",
   "race": 5,
   "ageC": "17 years",
   "age": 187
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "AB D",
   "race": 1,
   "ageC": "18 years",
   "age": 100
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "ABC E",
   "race": 1,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "ABCD",
   "race": 1,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "ABCDE",
   "race": 1,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "B",
   "race": 27,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "B H",
   "race": 0,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "B E",
   "race": 6,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "B D",
   "race": 6,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "B DE",
   "race": 2,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "BC",
   "race": 2,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "BCD",
   "race": 1,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "C",
   "race": 175,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "C E",
   "race": 17,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "CD",
   "race": 3,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "D",
   "race": 14,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "DE",
   "race": 3,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "E",
   "race": 481,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 },
 {
   "genderC": "",
   "gender": null,
   "raceC": "",
   "race": null,
   "ageC": "",
   "age": null
 }
]
```

Comment: I am going through the blockbuilder you shared and I am a bit confused what your final data is like? In the blockbuilder you have your data in dataset.json but it is just javascript as you have arrays of objects `var gender = [{..}],{..}]`. If your data is already in the form of arrays of objects you do not need to create the json. Having them as separate variables is actually easier.

Comment: @Coola I imported the json as a script in index.html and the arrays are been called into init(). Do you mean that I do not need to call it in index.html? I can just define the arrays in pieChart()?

Comment: @Coola I think what I hope to do is simply to use my own dataset to create three pie charts switched by buttons. The transition will have effect from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/j0hnsmith/5591116 with legend or label marking the colors. Tooltip effect will also be added to show percentage.

Comment: Yes you can just define the arrays in `main.js`. I understand what you would like, but copying code from other sources without understanding what they do is kind of making your current block a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Coola I moved those vars to init() in main.js. The code is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several issues with your code and I had to make several changes.

If I understand correctly the main idea for you was to redraw the pie charts depending on what data the user clicks on i.e. "Gender" "Age" or "Race".

1. The data for each of these is very different, i.e. different object key-value pairs. I made all the `count` keys the same (in the age dataset they were `Count`).
2. Since the data is very different the examples you show where the data gets updated may not apply here as the data does not transform in this case. Instead the approach I took was to just clear the div and redraw a pie chart. So the first thing it does is to clear the chart area and then begins drawing. This significantly reduces the amount of code needed (your main.js = >300 lines, whereas mine 138 lines)
3. I improved the tooltip as your data keys change so this needs to be accounted for in the tooltip.
4. I moved your data to a separate js file to not clutter the main.js. I just make sure to call that before the main.js in the index.html file.
5. I updated the `function color(d)` function to pick the colors from an array of objects based on the data keys. You can expand the array to your needs. If you want to use colors within a range you can use `var color = d3.scale.category20();` and call the color using the index of the data like `.attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i);})` as shown in this example http://bl.ocks.org/j0hnsmith/5591116

Here is a working block https://bl.ocks.org/akulmehta/923f277f8a10d0c35b77f6e3a84929bf/

Note that since a lot of data points for `age` and `race` are `0`, the animation stutters a bit. Also note that your labels are overlapping when you have arcs very close to each other. Hence I would suggest removing the labels.

Comment: Thank you for everything. You have even selected colors for the categorical variable. I will review/learn the code and make some revisions once I get back home today.

Comment: I will accept the answer once I'm home, my app is not letting me to mark the check for some reason.

Comment: I attempted to make few changes on your edited code. I added conditions in the else statement for colors that would define categories of race, but the race graph did not appear after the change. I also tried to add a legend to the graph after removing labels, but the legend is not appearing either. This is the old link with my updates: https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/38243015ab2ac96b6086d3bae56572b9

Comment: I will accept the answer now, but could you help to make the last few add-ons. I think I'm pretty close, but for some reason, the effects are not showing up.

Comment: What kind of add-ons? And the effects show up fine in my block so you will have to check your code.

Comment: I added var colorExtra in the else statement to define colors for race variable. In your updated code, race was set to all blue by default because the categories were not defined. I want to keep the colors you've defined for me, so I added a statement in the else condition part, but the entire pie graph of race stopped appearing. I made the updates in this link: blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/38243015ab2ac96b6086d3bae56572b9

Comment: How about this https://blockbuilder.org/akulmehta/1aa16d77c876b213d982c54a8e86e434 ? When calling the color more information is passed to the function to let it know what type of data it is and the length of the data. By doing that you can use it to use ordinal scales to get the color value. Hope this helps.